# Do I have to define every single operator?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, operators, operator-overloading

Suppose I have a struct with just one field:

```
public struct Angle
{
    public static readonly double RadiansPerDegree = Math.PI / 180;

    private readonly double _degrees;

    public Angle(double degrees)
    {
        _degrees = degrees;
    }

    public double Degrees
    {
        get { return _degrees; }
    }

    public double Radians
    {
        get { return _degrees * RadiansPerDegree; }
    }

    public static Angle FromDegrees(double value)
    {
        return new Angle(value);
    }

    public static Angle FromRadians(double value)
    {
        return new Angle(value / RadiansPerDegree);
    }
}
```

This works great, until I want to do stuff like this:

```
var alpha = Angle.FromDegrees(90);
var beta = Angle.FromDegrees(100);
var inequality = alpha > beta;
var sum = alpha + beta;
var negation = -alpha;
//etc.
```

So, I implemented `IEquatable<in T>` and `IComparable<in T>`, but that still didn't enable any operators (not even `==`, `<`, `>=`, etc.).

So, I started providing operator overloads.

For example:

```
public static Angle operator +(Angle a, Angle b)
{
    return new Angle(a._degrees + b._degrees);
}

public static Angle operator -(Angle a)
{
    return new Angle(-a._degrees);
}

public static bool operator >(Angle a, Angle b)
{
    return a._degrees > b._degrees;
}
```

This worked, however, when I looked at all the operators I could conceivably overload (`+, -, !, ~, ++, --, true, false, +, -, *, /, %, &, |, ^, <<, >>, ==, !=, <, >, <=, >=`), I started to feel like there must be a better way. After all, the struct only contains one field, and that field is a value type.

Is there some way to enable all the operators of `double` in one shot? Or do I really have to type out every operator I could possibly want to support by hand?

(Even if I had two or three fields, I'd still like to be able to add the operators in one batch...)

Comment: You could probably add implicit casts to (and possibly from) the `double` type to do that.  Though, something in my head tells me that might not be a good idea and could lead to ambiguity.

Comment: If you are really doing this just for the degree and radian conversion, why not just have a static MathHelper class that implements those feature and just use double instead of creating a class that re invents another class with a different name?

Comment: @Jeff Mercado, I think an implicit cast might be just what I'm looking for, actually. Would you consider converting your comment into an answer? Also, if there really is a downside, I'd really appreciate if you could expand on that a little. Thanks.

Comment: @DanM: That's kinda the problem, I don't really know if there is a downside to that and I have a weird feeling that there is. That made me reluctant to suggesting that as an answer.

Comment: @Jeff, fair enough, though making it an answer would give the community a better opportunity to weigh in. Looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx, it certainly seems like this particular example fits the intended usage of an implicit cast. You should be able to convert between any double and any angle (e.g., `Angle a = -720` would be interpreted as 0 degrees or 0 radians with no exception necessary). If the struct were `Distance` instead of `Angle`, it wouldn't be quite as straightforward, though. Can you have a negative distance?

Comment: @Jeff Mercado, followup: I did find one minor issue with using the implicit cast. See my comment to LaceySnr below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The point of overloading operators is to define how to add to manipulate objects of a custom type using those operators, so if your second field was a string array, how would you expect the ++ operator to be implemented automatically? There is no sensible answer, especially since we don't know the context of the object or it's usage, so the answer is *yes, you do have to overload the operators yourself*.

For the record, if you really do only need one field, and it's just a double, then don't use a struct in the first place unless you need to overload the operators to perform some other action than they do by default — it's a clear case of over-engineering!

Comment: The `Angle` example is a simplification, but my goal is to make it very clear what the units are, and to encapsulate the necessary conversion between units into a single type. So, if I have an `Angle`, there is no ambiguity about units, I just grab whichever I need. What I was getting at with my question was that, I wish there were some way to tell the compiler that I want the struct to behave as if it's the underlying field for all operations. @Jeff Mercado's suggestion to use implicit casts *seems* to accomplish that, but he seems concerned that there may be unintended consequences.

Comment: As soon as the types are something more complicated than the primitive ones then you can see how a system would not be able to generate meaningful operations for the data in question. At least you know what you're doing! I'd suggest maybe creating a macro in an IDE such as Vim for generating all of the operators for your structs if it's something you'll do more than once.

Comment: I think in all of my cases I foresee for this particular project, I can implicitly convert the whole type to a single native value type for the purposes of performing operations, but if I come across something more complex, the macro idea for generating the operator overloads sounds good.

Comment: Ahh, in writing some tests, I came across a problem with using an implicit cast: the sum of two `Angle`s is a `double`. You can explicitly convert back to an `Angle` (or set the result to a variable already declared as an `Angle`), but it's not as natural as if the individual operators were defined. So, looks like I might just have to bite the bullet.

Comment: Yeah I'm afraid even casting is just going to get ugly and awkward to maintain in the long run! As others have indicated, the best thing to do in this situation is to just create a few utility functions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must define every operator that you want to use. The compiler has no way of knowing what you want each operator to do, aside from the operators that are negatives of each other (and even those may not necessarily be obvious; what if you wanted to mimic standard SQL null behavior where both `==` and `!=` would return `false` when compared to null?).

Answer (score 0):

For most cases I agree with LaceySnr: it doesn't really work for any operators that return your new object (e.g. +, * ect.). For the comparators it could work (as in there could be an annotation that says "use this method's return value to stand in for for this object when used in all comparator operations"), but I don't know of anything like that.

I'm not sure what the limitations of annotations are in C#, but it may be possible to create one that does that (for the operators that return bool), but unless you were planning on using it very much I doubt it will be worth your time.

Having said this, if you were to have an object which took exactly one argument into the constructor, and that argument was the return value of the method, it should be possible to do it for that as well.

Of course to do any of this will require some pretty extreme class-tinkering, which I'm not really in a situation to give advice on...